# Win32 API Copy pictures files from a directory to new/existing directory

Tags: c++, windows

I want to copy all pictures file (like .jpeg, .bmp .gif) from "C:\" to a new/existing directory.
How can i write this? Something like (*.jpg|.bmp|.gif ) ???

Here is my code:

```
HANDLE hFile;
 WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
char *strTheNameOfTheFile=new char[MAX_PATH];
char folder[100]="D:\\myPictures\\";
char tempFolder[100]="D:\\myPictures\\";

SetCurrentDirectory("D:\\");
        hFile=FindFirstFile("*.jpg",&FindFileData);// Here is my problem | *.jpeg | *.bmp | *.gif
        strTheNameOfTheFile = FindFileData.cFileName;
        strcat(folder,strTheNameOfTheFile);
        CopyFileEx(strTheNameOfTheFile,folder,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
        MessageBox(hDlg,strTheNameOfTheFile,"Oh",MB_OK);
        strTheNameOfTheFile=NULL;
        folder[0]='\0';
        strcpy(folder,tempFolder);
        while(FindNextFile(hFile,&FindFileData))
        {

            strTheNameOfTheFile = FindFileData.cFileName;
            strcat(folder,strTheNameOfTheFile);
            CopyFileEx(strTheNameOfTheFile,folder,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
            strTheNameOfTheFile=NULL;
            folder[0]='\0';
            strcpy(folder,tempFolder);
        }
MessageBox(hDlg,"Done!","Finished",MB_OK);

FindClose(hFile);
```

Comment: Are you allocating memory for `strTheNameOfTheFile`? Try initializing it as a `char[MAX_PATH]`

Comment: Cool. That's the part taken care of that usually missing. Now for the part that _is_ missing - the question. What is it?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Random Davis, you don't understand. I want to know the syntax for FindFirstFile("*.jpg",&FindFileData); where first parameter contain multiple extensions in one string.

Comment: FindFirstFile does not appear to support this behavior directly; however, if you Find all files without filtering by extension, you can then choose based on whether the extension of the file matches any of the extensions you want to copy.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:  Put your code into a function (e.g., `CopyMyFiles`) that takes the extension as a parameter, and then you call that function once for each extension.

(Your code is a bit buggy, so you'll have to fix that up first.)

```
void CopyMyFiles(const char *pattern, const char *from, const char *to) {
  const auto wild = std::string(from) + pattern;
  WIN32_FIND_DATAA find_data;
  HANDLE hfind = ::FindFirstFileA(wild.c_str(), &find_data);
  if (hfind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    do {
      const auto source = std::string(from) + find_data.cFileName;
      const auto target = std::string(to) + find_data.cFileName;
      ::CopyFileExA(source.c_str(), target.c_str(),
        nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, 0);
    } while (::FindNextFileA(hfind, &find_data));
    ::FindClose(hfind);
  }
}
```

Then you can call this once for each pattern (extension).

```
const char *patterns[] = {"*.jpg", "*.gif", "*.bmp" };
const char *from = "D:\\";
const char *to = "D:\\pictures\\";
for (const auto &pattern : patterns)
  CopyMyFiles(pattern, from, to);
```

Option 2:  Enumerate all the files (using that pattern `"*"`) and copy just the ones that match one of your extensions.

Comment: Thankyou Adrian!
for (const auto &pattern : patterns) work like a foreach right?

Comment: Yes, that's a for-each in C++11 syntax.  If you're using an older compiler, you'll have to write a more verbose loop statement.